# How to return a final result from object designed to chain methods

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I am doing this exercise:

- To do this exercise, you will probably have to use `return self`.  If the method returns itself (an instance of itself), we can chain methods.
- Develop a ruby class called `MathDojo` that has the following functions: add, subtract. Have these 2 functions take at least 1 parameter. `MathDojo.new.add(2).add(2, 5).subtract(3, 2)` should perform `0+2+(2+5)-(3+2)` and return `4`.

I have this code:

```
class MathDojo
  def initialize
    @sum = 0
  end
  def add(*numbers)
    numbers.inject(@sum) { |sum, number| sum + number }
    self
  end
  def subtract(*numbers)
    numbers.inject(@sum) { |sum, number| sum - number }
    self
  end
end
```

Right now, my code returns:

```
MathDojo.new.add(2).add(2, 5).subtract(3, 2)
# => #<MathDojo:0x0000000160b0c0>
```

How do I return the instance variable of an object instead of the object itself? When I remove the return to `self`, the methods no longer chain, although I am able to make a single method call:

```
MathDojo.new.subtract(2,3)
# => -5
```

How do I modify my code so the chaining works as expected?

---

Self-solved, had to edit, because the downvotes on my question put me under the reputation needed to answer my own question. My apologies.

I needed to flatten the array before injecting numbers into the array. Then added attr_accessor to collect the sum for use outside the class. I also changed the implied return of self to read:

```
return self
```

I modified the code by entering the following, as shown by jbh's answer:

```
attr_accessor :sum
before my initialize method
```

Then I modified the add and subtract methods to include calling flatten:

```
@sum = numbers.flatten.inject(@sum) { |sum, number| sum + number }
@sum = numbers.flatten.inject(@sum) { |sum, number| sum - number }
```

then as jbh also showed I added .sum to my chained methods:

```
puts math1 = MathDojo.new.add(2).add(2, 5).subtract(3, 2).sum
```

One more thing, people talk about how curmudgeony the problem solver-people on stackoverflow can be and today I experienced that. I clearly mentioned I was new to Ruby (I should have stated it's only my 2nd day) and I had to have my reputation voted down 2 points because they didn't like the format of my question, all that needed to be done was the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot know when a method is called if there will be a chain call after it. So you cannot choose if you should return self or the sum value.

Simple answer for that, create a sum method that should be called at the end of your chain call

```
class MathDojo
  attr_reader :sum
end

puts MathDojo.new.add(2).add(2, 5).subtract(3, 2).sum
```

Comment: This did not fix the problem. I needed to also flatten the arrays the sums were injected into.

Comment: I deliberately answer your question about chaining only. As your were doing an execercise, I would not want to spoil you solution